# Titanium TableView Accordion

Tags: javascript, user-interface, titanium, accordion

I'm just about to extend the TableView object of Appcelerators Titanium to allow for hiding and showing rows in accordion-style.

Wondering if anybody has already a solution or a good suggestion that I should take into account.

Answer (score 0):

TableViewRow has a hide() and a show() method: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-object

However, these don't work. 
What I ended up doing was to put a table inside a row, resize it when clicked and after resizing the table, call setHeight('auto') so that the row adjusts. It actually automatically animates the height-change (Although the animation looks a bit broken), I'll make a proper little helper function out of this soon enough. For now, here's the snippet if it helps anybody:

```
// Toggle Accordion
settingsTable.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    alert(B.helper.var_dump(innertable));
    if(e.index === 2){
        if(innertable.height === 200){
            innertable.height = 45;
            row3.setHeight('auto');
        }else{

            //alert(B.helper.var_dump(settingsTable.data[0].rows[3]));
            innertable.height = 200;
            row3.setHeight('auto');
        }
    }
});
```